# How can I split a stream on either carriage return (\r) or CRLF (\r\n) line terminators?

Tags: split, rust, carriage-return

I'm trying to split an odd serial port stream that separates lines with carriage-return `\r` and sometimes `\r\n`. `BufReader` has the `lines` function, but it only splits on `\n` or `\r\n`. There is a `.read_until(...)` function, but it only works for a single terminator.

Based on the [standard library's implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/190feb65290d39d7ab6d44e994bd99188d339f16/src/libstd/io/mod.rs#L1707), I've started to [cobble together](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3ef1779ac6e038dae456d2b205f08e57) some bits, but I haven't gotten it to compile yet. I hope I'm doing this right the "Rust way". Regular expressions  seem too expensive for a byte stream.

#### Example input:

```
Heading:\r\nLine 1\rLine 2\rLine 3\r\nEnd
```

When you use `lines()` on that input, you get three lines because `\r` is not considered a line terminator:

```
Heading:
Line 1\rLine 2\rLine 2\rLine 3
End
```

Comment: @trentcl updated question with example. Carriage return \r is not considered a line terminator.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55743

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm still not really sure what you're asking. Code review doesn't seem appropriate since it's not compiling. If you are stuck getting it to compile, note that a [mcve] should be provided "*in the question itself*"

Comment: @trentcl, I'm trying to split a string stream on \n, \r\n but most importantly \r. You are welcome to edit my question with the content from my Rust playground link, but it will be out-of-date almost immediately. The solution is probably more trivial than the edit to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on my previous answer on [github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55743#issuecomment-436937262) to match your need:

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::str;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyLines<B> {
    buffer: B,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    Io(std::io::Error),
    Utf8(std::str::Utf8Error),
}

impl<B> MyLines<B> {
    pub fn new(buffer: B) -> Self {
        Self { buffer }
    }
}

impl<B: BufRead> Iterator for MyLines<B> {
    type Item = Result<String, MyError>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let (line, total) = {
            let buffer = match self.buffer.fill_buf() {
                Ok(buffer) => buffer,
                Err(e) => return Some(Err(MyError::Io(e))),
            };
            if buffer.is_empty() {
                return None;
            }
            let consumed = buffer
                .iter()
                .take_while(|c| **c != b'\n' && **c != b'\r')
                .count();
            let total = consumed
                + if consumed < buffer.len() {
                    // we found a delimiter
                    if consumed + 1 < buffer.len() // we look if we found two delimiter
                    && buffer[consumed] == b'\r'
                    && buffer[consumed + 1] == b'\n'
                    {
                        2
                    } else {
                        1
                    }
                } else {
                    0
                };
            let line = match str::from_utf8(&buffer[..consumed]) {
                Ok(line) => line.to_string(),
                Err(e) => return Some(Err(MyError::Utf8(e))),
            };
            (line, total)
        };
        self.buffer.consume(total);

        Some(Ok(line))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = BufReader::new("Heading:\r\nLine 1\rLine 2\rLine 3\r\nEnd".as_bytes());

    for line in MyLines::new(f) {
        println!("{:?}", line);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ok("Heading:")
Ok("Line 1")
Ok("Line 2")
Ok("Line 3")
Ok("End")
```

Comment: This could result in shorter line than expected cause we don't loop over `fill_buf()`, working on better code.